# Python finding numbers from a list that satisfy a specific condition

Tags: python, algorithm, binary

Good evening, I am currently having some problems implementing a binary search algorithm, which extracts the amount of numbers in a list that satisfy this condition

Suppose **Sorted** list A = [1,2,4,5,6,7,8] I need to find the amount of numbers that satisfy this condition.

Absolute(A[i] - i) <= C where C is a number specified by the user for example

|A[i] -i|<= C  <---- That is the condition I need to satisfy, i need to find the amount of numbers that are in the list that fulfil this condition.

Example:

```
    A = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
    c = 4

    A[0] = | 1 - 0 |  = 1.
    A[1] = | 2 - 1 |  = 1.
    A[2] = | 4 - 2 |  = 2.
    A[3] = | 8 - 3 |  = 5.
    A[4] = | 16 - 4 | = 12.
    A[5] = | 32 - 5 | = 27.
    A[6] = | 64 - 6 | = 58.
```

Now I realise I need to use binary search to ensure my running time is in O(log N) time, but I am not sure where do I put the condition/if statement.

Can someone please show me how this would look in python code. Thank you so much for the assistance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't see how binary search would work here, because your condition depends on the item's position in the list.

Comment: I have tried a binary search using pythons bisect module, but no luck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python Bisect module

Use a [key with binary_search module](https://gist.github.com/ericremoreynolds/2d80300dabc70eebc790) to allow function evaluations

```
from bisect import bisect_left

class KeyifyList(object):
    " Allows specifying a key with binary search module"
    def __init__(self, inner, key):
        self.inner = inner
        self.key = key

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.inner)

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.key((k, self.inner[k]))

def bin_search(a, c):
  # Binary search for placement
  # Using key function to allow binary search using a function
  # Computes abs(a[i] - i) at places where binary search is evaluated
  # key computes abs(a[k]-k)
  # Binary search so O(log(n)) time complexity
  i = bisect_left(KeyifyList(a, lambda kv: abs(kv[1]-kv[0])), c)

  if i == len(a):
    last_index = len(a) -1
    if abs(a[last_index] - last_index) <= c:
      return len(a)  # all indices satisfy
    else:
      i = last_index

  while i >= 0 and abs(a[i]-i) > c:
    # this is normally a one point move over
    # so O(1) rather than O(n) in time complexity
    i -= 1
  
  # number of points is one more than index to satisfy
  return i + 1
```

**Test**

```
A = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
c = 4
```

*Test c from 0 to 63*

```
for c in range(65):
  print(f'c = {c}, number of points = {bin_search(A, c)}')
```

*Output*

```
c = 0, number of points = 0
c = 1, number of points = 1
c = 2, number of points = 3
c = 3, number of points = 3
c = 4, number of points = 3
c = 5, number of points = 4
c = 6, number of points = 4
c = 7, number of points = 4
c = 8, number of points = 4
c = 9, number of points = 4
c = 10, number of points = 4
c = 11, number of points = 4
c = 12, number of points = 5
c = 13, number of points = 5
c = 14, number of points = 5
c = 15, number of points = 5
c = 16, number of points = 5
c = 17, number of points = 5
c = 18, number of points = 5
c = 19, number of points = 5
c = 20, number of points = 5
c = 21, number of points = 5
c = 22, number of points = 5
c = 23, number of points = 5
c = 24, number of points = 5
c = 25, number of points = 5
c = 26, number of points = 5
c = 27, number of points = 6
c = 28, number of points = 6
c = 29, number of points = 6
c = 30, number of points = 6
c = 31, number of points = 6
c = 32, number of points = 6
c = 33, number of points = 6
c = 34, number of points = 6
c = 35, number of points = 6
c = 36, number of points = 6
c = 37, number of points = 6
c = 38, number of points = 6
c = 39, number of points = 6
c = 40, number of points = 6
c = 41, number of points = 6
c = 42, number of points = 6
c = 43, number of points = 6
c = 44, number of points = 6
c = 45, number of points = 6
c = 46, number of points = 6
c = 47, number of points = 6
c = 48, number of points = 6
c = 49, number of points = 6
c = 50, number of points = 6
c = 51, number of points = 6
c = 52, number of points = 6
c = 53, number of points = 6
c = 54, number of points = 6
c = 55, number of points = 6
c = 56, number of points = 6
c = 57, number of points = 6
c = 58, number of points = 7
c = 59, number of points = 7
c = 60, number of points = 7
c = 61, number of points = 7
c = 62, number of points = 7
c = 63, number of points = 7
c = 64, number of points = 7
```

**Performance Testing**

Compare to list comprehension (O(n) algorithm)

```
def list_comprehension_method(a, c):
  " Use list comprehension to find number of points "
  return len([1 for i, v in enumerate(A) if abs(v - i) <= c])
```

*Timing Test*

Create a large random array

```
n = 10000   # number of points in array
c = n // 4  # c value
A = sorted([randint(1, n) for _ in range(n)])

print(timeit(lambda: bin_search(A, c), number=100))
# Time: 0.00173 seconds
print(timeit(lambda: list_comprehension_method(A, c), number=100))
# Time: 0.49982 seconds
```

Binary search **~289X faster** for n = 10, 000

Comment: Unfortunately you inadvertently helped someone cheat, see [OP trying to hide evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62046152/revisions). This is why it's better to only answer questions with effort put into them.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--you're probably right.  Primarily answered to help others such as DeepAlgo212345 and JohnGordon who from the comments tried, but couldn't figure out how to use a function with Python's bisect method (something which I also wondered about previously until I ran into how to key functions with Python bisect method so wanted to help spread the word).  It's surprising the number of homework, coding challenges, etc. questions with the poster obviously putting in no effort.  To help clean up the site--should I flag these in the future as needing moderator intervention?

Comment: No, these aren't really moderator concerns. If you see a question that's clearly someone trying to have others do their work/homework/exam for them, just vote to close as "needs more focus" (formerly "too broad") and refrain from answering until the asker has demonstrated a genuine attempt at solving the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

lambda and filter should get you there

```
A = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]
c = 4
res = list(filter(lambda x: A[x] - x <= c, range(len(A))))
print(res)
```

`[0, 1, 2]`

Comment: I don't think this runs in log N time though.

Comment: Unfortunately you inadvertently helped someone cheat, see [OP trying to hide evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62046152/revisions). This is why it's better to only answer questions with effort put into them.